# What to do with the [pow] tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

On Stack Overflow, there is a [pow](/questions/tagged/pow) tag.
Its info reads:

> Pow is a zero-config Rack server for Mac OS X created by 37signals.

However, most of the questions that are tagged with this tag actually refer to the `pow` function that appears in various languages.

What should be done about this?

**EDIT:** Made plan of action into answer

Comment: It would've been nice to get a "go for it" comment with a few likes (or "don't do it") (in case you think the question / answer isn't worth reputation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suggested plan of action:**

1. Change the info to something like:

   > pow is a function that exists in various programming languages that usually takes two numbers as input and returns the first number to the power of the second number. DO NOT USE THIS TAG for questions relating to the Rack server, use [rack-pow] instead.
2. Create a new tag

   Something like [rack-pow](/questions/tagged/rack-pow), [mac-pow](/questions/tagged/mac-pow) or [rack-mac-pow](/questions/tagged/rack-mac-pow)
3. Manually retag all applicable questions with the new tag

I personally don't think going the other way would be better (i.e. leaving the info as is and creating a new tag for the `pow` function). The Rack server is less common.